# Remove leading zeros from time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have time series with the following pattern and I am wondering whether somebody could share a smart trick to remove the leading zeros. The reason why I want to avoid is that it may have a negative implication on the selection of forecasting models.

Example time series:

```
TimeSeries <- ts(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 10, 10, 16, 7, 13, 0, 9, 1, 
                   11, 2, 11, 3, 11, 4, 1, 20, 13, 18, 19, 16, 16, 16, 
                   15, 14, 27, 24, 35, 8, 18, 21, 20, 19, 22, 18, 21
),start=c(2001,6),frequency=12)
```

I can imagine a procedure of narrowing down the leading series of zeros with performing multiple tests with subsets of the time series and then removing the leading subset with only zeros. However, this will be a cumbersome procedure, which is likely to be inefficient in terms of computation.

Is anybody aware of an already existing function or procedure to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This removes only the leading zeros and leaves in the other zeros:

```
TimeSeries[cumsum(TimeSeries)!=0]
#[1]  9 10 10 16  7 13  0  9  1 11  2 11  3 11  4  1 20 13 18 19 16 16 16 15 14 27 24 35  8 18 21 20 19 22 18 21
```

**Why is this doing the trick?**
The out put of the `cumsum` is:

```
cumsum(TimeSeries)
 [1]   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9  19  29  45  52  65  65  74  75
[33]  86  88  99 102 113 117 118 138 151 169 188 204 220 236 251 265 292 316 351 359 377 398 418 418 437 459 477 498
```

Thus, only in cases where there are only zeros the result is equal to zero. In case there is a zero somewhere halfway in the time series the cumsum will not change but won't be zero.

If there are negative values in the timeseries you can use:

```
TimeSeries[cumsum(abs(TimeSeries))!=0]
```

Comment: Note that this only works (reliably) if the TimeSeries in non-negative. If `TimeSeries <- c(0, 1, -1)`, it fails. If TimeSeries is indeed non-negative, it is of course faster than a solution with `min(which(TimeSeries!=0))`.

Comment: Additionally, if you are running this on a data frame, df, where column=TimeSeries, you can run  ```df[cumsum(df$TimesSeries),]``` to return the data frame sans leading zeroes, or ```df$TimeSeries[cumsum(df$TimeSeries)]]``` to return  only the sans leading zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would also be:

```
yourts <- c(0,1,1,0,1,2,3) 
yourts_wo_zeros <- yourts[which.max(yourts != 0):length(yourts)]
```

because `which.max` takes the first maximum value, of in this case `False, True, True, ...`

I assume it should be sligthly more computationally efficient than cumsum, because it avoids possibly large numbers

Answer (score 1):

`TimeSeries[TimeSeries != 0]`... works for me, probably is a better way out there, though:

```
> TimeSeries <- ts(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 10, 10, 16, 7, 13, 0, 9, 1, 
                   11, 2, 11, 3, 11, 4, 1, 20, 13, 18, 19, 16, 16, 16, 
                   15, 14, 27, 24, 35, 8, 18, 21, 20, 19, 22, 18, 21
),start=c(2001,6),frequency=12)
> TimeSeries[TimeSeries != 0]
 [1]  9 10 10 16  7 13  9  1 11  2 11  3 11  4  1 20 13 18 19 16 16 16 15 14 27
[26] 24 35  8 18 21 20 19 22 18 21
>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This will remove all `zeros` in the time series. Thus if say a zero was included in the before last position, this code would also remove that. So it is not strictly focused on removing leading zeros but removes all zeros.

Comment: Your example. only had leading zeros, but I agree @Roland's solution is better, even if there's no explanation given

Comment: True true. I've added the explanation of why this is working to @Roland's solution. Once I saw his code it was pretty straight forward to understand.